# Windows 8 not picking up mic sound

Tags: windows-8, audio, microphone

I have been using an older logitech headset and both the sound and mic had been working perfectly.  I purchased a new turtle beach headset and somewhere around this time the mic stopped picking up sound.  I went back to the logitech and the same problem was there.  I tried both headphones in another computer and they worked perfectly.  I purchased a new sound card and the same problem occurs with both headsets.  I upgraded from Windows 8 to 8.1 and still nothing.  I've changed all the mic settings I could find (communications, mic levels, made sure application can't take exclusive control, etc) and nothing.    I've upgraded drivers for both sound cards, I've ran troubleshooting, and I've googled.  Oh how I've googled.

Anyone happen to have any suggestions?  My next step will be to reformat but is there something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you sure, you have the correct thing checked? http://puu.sh/6uZpQ.png

Comment: i personally think you really went off into a tangant on this problem getting another sound card, upgrading windows, Its possible the 2 sound cards might be conflicting with each other. I'd start back at square 1 and see if you can isolate the problem again. What about the volume settings on the microphone? are you sure it wasn't muted.

Comment: @Sickest I've definitely checked whether the mic was muted.  I've tried to headsets with a mic and checked whether both or either were muted.  I've messed with every volume setting I could find.  Tried moving things up/down/middle.  I've definitely put 5+ hours into this.  I've listened to the device and there is background sound but no voice at all.  I got the other sound card because I didn't know what else to try.  It's the only mic I have plugged in and it's the one that's default.  I've tried to turn on everything in that picture.

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone in Control Panel, and changed the microphone settings, or adjust the settings.

Or even allowed your program to access your microphone through PC Settings, because you might of forbidden access to your microphone.